# How to subtract row means from each row

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix or data frame `gene`like this:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]    2   12    4   10  
[2,]    3   14    3   9  
[3,]    5   15    4   3  
[4,]    8   6    12   18
```

And I already get the means of each row and each column by:

```
a <- apply(gene, 1, mean)
b <- apply(gene, 2, mean)
```

And now I want to subtract row means from each row and get this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]   -5   5    -3   3  
[2,] -4.25 6.75 -4.25 1.75    
[3,] -1.75 8.25 -2.75 -3.75  
[4,]    -3   -5    1   7
```

which means the rowmeans of the new matrix is all 0.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the function `rowMeans`

```
gene - rowMeans(gene)
        V1    V2    V3    V4
[1,] -5.00  5.00 -3.00  3.00
[2,] -4.25  6.75 -4.25  1.75
[3,] -1.75  8.25 -2.75 -3.75
[4,] -3.00 -5.00  1.00  7.00
```

Comment: Thx! I get this before, but when I checked my result, the R gave me a lot of e-16 for row means of new matrix, which made me so confused. Because you know if the operation is right, the row means of the new matrix should all be 0.

Answer (score 6):

Use `sweep()`:

```
gene <- matrix(c(2,12,4,10,3,14,3,
                 9,5,15,4,3,8,6,12,18), 
      byrow=TRUE,nrow=4)
gene2 <- sweep(gene, MARGIN=1, STATS= rowMeans(gene))
```

Subtracting the row means as suggested by @G5W works, but only because of an interaction between two underlying properties of R: (1) automatic replication of vectors to the appropriate length when operating on unequal-length vectors; (2) column-major storage of matrices.